# Goldengate 19 Postgres to AWS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, oracle-golden-gate

Ok, so I have one I can't crack.  I am testing on-prem GG to AWS.  I have it set up in a hub config on-prem.  I have my Postgres DB on AWS set with rds.force_ssl=1.  I have copied down the certificate bundles from AWS.

I basically followed these steps from Oracle.
[GG documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/goldengate/core/19.1/securing/configuring-ssl-support-postgresql.html)

And AWS steps here.
[AWS PostGres SSL Steps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.SSL.html)

My ODBCINI has as follows:

```
 sbpgdb=PostgreSQL on sbpgdb [ODBC] 
 IANAAppCodePage=4 
 InstallDir=/u01/app/oracle/product/ggpgsdb 
 [sbpgdb]Driver=/u01/app/oracle/product/ggpgsdb/lib/GGpsql25.so 
 Description=DataDirect 7.1 PostgreSQL Wire Protocol 
 BatchMechanism=2 
 Database=bob_test 
 HostName=my_rds_instance.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com 
 PortNumber=5432 
 TransactionErrorBehavior=2 
 EncryptionMethod=1 
 ValidateServerCertificate=1 
 TrustStore=/home/oracle/certs/us-east-1-bundle.pem
```

My replicat is this.

```
REPLICAT intrepg

ASSUMETARGETDEFS

HANDLECOLLISIONS
 SETENV (NLSLANG=AL32UTF8)
 SETENV (NLS_LANG="AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8")
 SETENV ( PGCLIENTENCODING = "UTF8" )
 SETENV (ODBCINI="/u01/app/oracle/product/ggpgsdb/odbc.ini" )
 targetdb sbpgdb, USERIDALIAS pg_postgresdb
 discardfile ./dirrpt/bob.dsc, APPEND, megabytes 20
 reportcount every 60 seconds, rate
 map mypdb.bob.*, target bob_test.*;
```

I can run this command and it connects to the DB.

```
 dblogin sourcedb sbpgdb useridalias pg_postgresdb
```

but if I start my replicat I get this and it abends after a few seconds.

```
2021-06-23T09:46:53.835-0500  ERROR   OGG-00551  Oracle GoldenGate Delivery for PostgreSQL, intrepg.prm:  Database operation failed: Couldn't connect to sbpgdb. ODBC error: SQLSTATE 08001 native database error 7570. [Oracle][ODBC PostgreSQL Wire Protocol driver]SSL Handshake Failure reason [EOF observed which violates protocol].
```

Now I can disable the whole SSL thing and it connects and the replicat starts right up.  What have I done wrong?

Comment: The PostgreSQL log file may tell you.

Comment: Ok, it seems that even dblogin can be extremely slow and even timeout.  if it does timeout I get the error above and if I immediately run dblogin again it works.  Now if I remove the requirement for ssl from postgres and the odbc file on GG it connects and works just like it is supposed to.

Comment: here is what shows up in the postgres logfile and just hangs there.  2021-06-24 20:07:42 UTC:128.62.208.183(17596):[unknown]@[unknown]:[8125]:LOG: connection received: host=128.62.208.183 port=17596.  This will show up on a good connection but the next line shows my connection name and DB.

Comment: Is this the reason Oracle and AWS tell you to put the endpoint for the hub on an EC2 instance?

Comment: oh and as a side note if i use psql with the same cert it connects very fast.

Comment: I wondered what the PostgreSQL log line is that corresponds to a failed connection - there must be a `FATAL` somewhere.

Comment: Checking the postgres log file helped me figure it.